# Why GetAllActorsOfClass returns empty?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unreal-blueprint

I have a `PlayerControl.cpp` class which derives from Pawn class

In that class , I have a method to get all Actors in Map

```
TSubclassOf<AEnemy> ClassToFind;
 TArray<AActor*> FoundEnemies;
 UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(GetWorld(), ClassToFind, FoundEnemies);
```

But FoundEnemies array is always empty , When I do the same thing in BP it works.

Can someone tell me why is this not working in C++ ? Or If I am doing wrong , How to do it correct ?

Comment: We are missing quite a bit of code here to help you there. First: try to write variable names beginning with a lowercase please. This is mostly standard and confuses others more. Second: does `GetAllActorsOfClass` take the array by reference?

Comment: Seriously down voting ? , I don't understand why down vote this question ? , lol

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hayt , I hop you've noticed this question's tags , This question is about programming with Unreal,  Anyone who used to be working with unreal would understand this code and it's references. :)

Comment: @Hayt   This is an unreal specific method which you won't find in plain C++ GetAllActorsOfClass , Sorry to say next time please check question's tags before commenting , answering or voting.

Comment: It still lacks information. I assume `AEnemy` is your class? How is it declared? How do you add them to the world? Anything which might make your code not-behave like it is intended to be. (if this would be all native unreal code without anything from you this would else be a bug in the unreal engine ;) )

Comment: @Hayt AEnemy is a class which inherit from Actor class , That's what I said Unreal Developers would know that.

Comment: Using uppercase variables is actually the standard in UE4, so the edit to the post was uncalled for in my opinion.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld  In-deed, you are correct

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally , I found answer for my own question

I should assign a value to the variable "ClassToFind" 
So adding line `classToFind = AEnemy::StaticClass();` fixed the  issue

```
TSubclassOf<AEnemy> classToFind;
    classToFind = AEnemy::StaticClass();
    TArray<AActor*> foundEnemies;
    UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(GetWorld(), classToFind, foundEnemies);
```

Comment: You can even skip the classToFind variable and just do:

    UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(GetWorld(), AEnemy::StaticClass(), foundEnemies);